# Looping javascript without change the loop of main loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, conditional-statements

How to make the else if condition using loop so it will be more efficient. without change the output

the else if contition will looping until 22 times, the array that is consist will be increased by the data.order.length

example:

```
else if data.order.length == 2
```

so the if condition will be like

```
(data.order[0].schedule_id == data.schedule[i].id || data.order[1].schedule_id == data.schedule[i].id)
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.schedule.length; i++) {
  if (data.order.length == 0) {
    const markup = `<div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 mt-2 me-xl-4 text-center"> <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="schedule_id" id="${data.schedule[i].id}" autocomplete="off" value="${data.schedule[i].id}">
      <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" for="${data.schedule[i].id}">${data.schedule[i].start}</label></div>`;
    document
      .querySelector("#myTime")
      .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
  }

  else if (data.order.length == 1) {
    if (data.order[0].schedule_id == data.schedule[i].id) {
      const markup = `<div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 mt-2 me-xl-4 text-center"> <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="schedule_id" id="${data.schedule[i].id}" autocomplete="off" value="${data.schedule[i].id}" disabled>
              <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" for="${data.schedule[i].id}">${data.schedule[i].start}</label></div>`;
      document
        .querySelector("#myTime")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
    } else {
      const markup = `<div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 mt-2 me-xl-4 text-center"> <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="schedule_id" id="${data.schedule[i].id}" autocomplete="off" value="${data.schedule[i].id}">
              <label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" for="${data.schedule[i].id}">${data.schedule[i].start}</label></div>`;
      document
        .querySelector("#myTime")
        .insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", markup);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to compare each element to all the elements that came before it in the array? or just to the previous element? You'll need to clarify what it is you're trying to achieve for more concrete help, this is sounding a lot like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Well Could you be more verbose with your question ?  Consider editing your original question with a solid example.

Answer (score 0):

I have optimized with functional concepts. Used `break` to stop further execution. Hope this answers your question

```js
(function insertMarkup(data, selector, tag) {
    //function toinject the markup
    function inject(markup) {
        document
            .querySelector(selector)
            .insertAdjacentHTML(tag, markup);
    }

    //function to generate the markup
    function generateMarkup(id, start, disablgedFlag) {
        return '<div class="col-4 col-sm-3 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-1 mt-2 me-xl-4 text-center"> <input type="radio" class="btn-check" name="schedule_id" id=' + id + 'autocomplete="off" value=' + id + (disablgedFlag ? 'disabled >' : '>') +
            '<label class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-dark" for=' + id + '>' + start + '</label></div>';

    }
    //loop
    for (var i = 0; i < data.schedule.length; i++) {
        if (data.order.length == 0) {
            const markup = generateMarkup(data.schedule[i].id, data.schedule[i].start, false)
            inject(markup);
            //will stop the execution and break the for loop
            break;
        }

        else if (data.order.length == 1) {
            if (data.order[0].schedule_id == data.schedule[i].id) {
                const markup = generateMarkup(data.schedule[i].id, data.schedule[i].start, true)
                inject(markup);
            } else {
                const markup = generateMarkup(data.schedule[i].id, data.schedule[i].start, false)
                inject(markup);
            }
        }
    }
})(data, "#myTime", "beforeend")
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but i need the looping for else if condition, because  i need to loop it until 22 conditions